# How to randomly shuffle items across nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I'm currently doing a uni project that requires me to randomly shuffle items across nested lists.

Let's say I have a nested list that contains the name of a person, the food they had for dinner, and the time they ate their dinner, which looks something like this:

```
food = [['person1', 'food1', 'dinner time1'],
        ['person2', 'food2', 'dinner time2'], 
        ['person3', 'food3', 'dinner time3'],
        ...]
```

Is there a way I could randomly reshuffle the list so that each person will have different food and time for dinner, which looks something like this:

```
food_reshuffle = [['person2', 'food3', 'dinner time3'],
                  ['person1', 'food2', 'dinner time2'],
                  ['person3', 'food1', 'dinner time1']
                  ...]
```

Comment: So you really have *columns* and want to randomise each?

Comment: Looks like just shuffling the first column

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but my data are stored in a list

Comment: @tyc_8991: as Mad points out, your sample output has only randomised the pairings of people with `(foodN, dinner_timeN)`. Is that expected or should the `foodN` and `dinner_timeN` columns be shuffled independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate out the lists into *columns*, then shuffle each column and re-combine them.

To get the columns as lists, use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with the outer list applied as *separate* arguments, with the `*args` syntax. `zip()` returns tuples, but we need lists if we want to shuffle so I used `map()` to convert each.

```
people, foods, dinner_times = map(list, zip(*food))
```

Because each *row* is passed in as an argument, `zip()` pairs up the first value of each row as one tuple, the next row as another tuple, etc.

Now you have three separate lists, that you can each pass to [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

random.shuffle(people)
random.shuffle(foods)
random.shuffle(dinner_times)
```

Then re-combine, again with `zip()`:

```
food_reshuffle = [list(row) for row in zip(people, foods, dinner_times)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import random
>>> food = [['person1', 'food1', 'dinner time1'],
...         ['person2', 'food2', 'dinner time2'],
...         ['person3', 'food3', 'dinner time3'],
... ]
>>> people, foods, dinner_times = map(list, zip(*food))
>>> random.shuffle(people)
>>> random.shuffle(foods)
>>> random.shuffle(dinner_times)
>>> food_reshuffle = [list(row) for row in zip(people, foods, dinner_times)]
>>> pprint(food_reshuffle)
[['person2', 'food2', 'dinner time1'],
 ['person3', 'food3', 'dinner time2'],
 ['person1', 'food1', 'dinner time3']]
```

If you only wanted to shuffle the *first* column, with the other columns shuffled as a whole (so you end up with `'personA'` paired with the *pair* `('foodB', 'dinner timeB')`, then I'd shuffle the outer list or a copy thereof *first*, then separate out the people column for shuffling and recombining. To avoid having to make a copy, you can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to take random sampling from an input sequence, that just *happens* to be the same length. That happens to give the same result as using `random.shuffle()`, but without the need to copy the input sequence first and shuffle in-place:

```
import random

shuffled = random.sample(food, len(food))
people, *other = zip(*shuffled)
food_reshuffle = [[p, *o] for p, o in zip(random.sample(people, len(people), *other)]
```

which has this result:

```
>>> shuffled = random.sample(food, len(food))
>>> people, *other = zip(*shuffled)
>>> food_reshuffle = [list(row) for row in zip(random.sample(people, len(people)), *other)]
>>> pprint(food_reshuffle)
[['person2', 'food2', 'dinner time2'],
 ['person1', 'food3', 'dinner time3'],
 ['person3', 'food1', 'dinner time1']]
```

I used another 'trick' where we assign the first result of `zip(...)` to `people` and *everything else* to `other`, by using `*other` in the assignment.

Otherwise, if you have a variable number of columns that all need shuffling independently, just use a loop over `zip(*food)` and append each shuffled column to a `columns` list, so you can then recombine those again with `zip(*columns)`.

That's easily combined into a function:

```
import random

def shuffle_columns(list_of_rows):
    columns = []
    for column in zip(*list_of_rows):
        # shuffled list of column values
        shuffled = random.sample(column, len(column))
        columns.append(shuffled)
    return [list(row) for row in zip(*columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just shuffle the first column relative to the others, you can extract and reassign it:

```
first = [entry[0] for entry in people]
random.shuffle(first)
for entry, person in zip(people,  first):
    entry[0] = person
```

If you need the whole thing shuffled, you can do that once the first column is shuffled relative to the others:

```
random.shuffle(people)
```

If you want to sort by person, you can do that as well:

```
people.sort()
```

Comment: The other columns are also shuffled, but together as a single unit, it appears.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. That's fairly trivial as well. Either way you end up doing two shuffles.